# Why is this SQL server script to import XML file hanging?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to import data from an XML file in to SQL server.

I've run the below code but it just keeps executing ( for ages without doing anything / no errors).  It should only be 850 rows.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried just running with one field but same.

[XML file](https://www.foodstandards.gov.scot/downloads/Food_Hygiene_Information_Scheme_-_East_Lothian_Council.xml) - I removed hyphen from title "-_"!

```
CREATE DATABASE FoodStandards
GO

USE FoodStandards
GO

DROP TABLE FoodHygieneInfo;
CREATE TABLE FoodHygieneInfo
(
  FHRSID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  LocalAuthorityBusinessID VARCHAR(10), 
  BusinessName VARCHAR(10),
  BusinessType VARCHAR(25),
  BusinessTypeID INT,
  AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50),
  RatingValue VARCHAR(10),
  RatingKey VARCHAR(20),
  RatingDate DATETIME,
  LocalAuthorityCode INT,
  LocalAuthorityName VARCHAR(20),
  LocalAuthorityWebSite VARCHAR(30),
  LocalAuthorityEmailAddress VARCHAR(30),
  Scores INT,
  SchemeType VARCHAR(10),
  NewRatingPending VARCHAR(10),
  Geocode VARCHAR(50)
)
;

insert into FoodHygieneInfo
select 
A.establishment.query('FHRSID').value('.', 'INT') as FHRSID,
A.establishment.query('LocalAuthorityBusinessID').value('.', 'varchar(10)') as LocalAuthorityBusinessID,
A.establishment.query('BusinessName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') as BusinessName,
A.establishment.query('BusinessType').value('.', 'VARCHAR(25)') as BusinessType,
A.establishment.query('BusinessTypeID').value('.', 'INT') as BusinessTypeID,
A.establishment.query('AddressLine1').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') as AddressLine1,
A.establishment.query('RatingValue').value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') as RatingValue,
A.establishment.query('RatingKey').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') as RatingKey,
A.establishment.query('RatingDate').value('.', 'DATETIME') as RatingDate,
A.establishment.query('LocalAuthorityCode').value('.', 'INT') as LocalAuthorityCode,
A.establishment.query('LocalAuthorityName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)') as LocalAuthorityName,
A.establishment.query('LocalAuthorityWebSite').value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)') as LocalAuthorityWebSite,
A.establishment.query('LocalAuthorityEmailAddress').value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)') as LocalAuthorityEmailAddress,
A.establishment.query('Scores').value('.', 'INT') as Scores,
A.establishment.query('SchemeType').value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') as SchemeType,
A.establishment.query('NewRatingPending').value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') as NewRatingPending,
A.establishment.query('Geocode').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') as Geocode
from 
(select cast(c as xml) from
  openrowset (BULK 'C:\Food_Hygiene_Information_Scheme_East_Lothian_Council.xml', 
            SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(c)
) AS S(c)
CROSS APPLY c.nodes('FHRSEstablishment/EstablishmentCollection/EstablishmentDetail') as A(establishment);


--select* from FoodHygieneInfo;
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the bulk load first?

Comment: Actually it did work... after 57 minutes of seemingly doing nothing :-). I think I'll put it down to a PC that's seen better days!!

Comment: you may have been encountering something like this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30947/3690